# I want to change a number to a hours:minutes

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

I want to do a request that change a number up to 4 digits`('X', 'XX', 'XXX'or 'XXXX')` to a format `HH:MM`

For instance, I expect the output to be like this:

```
7    => 00:07
17   => 00:17
317  => 03:17
2317 => 23:17
```

I tried something like that

```sql
select  substr(X,0,2)||':'||substr(X,3,2) from TABLE
```

where X is an up to 4 digit number

but the actual output is:

```
7    => 7:
17   => 17:
317  => 31:7
2317 => 23:17
```

What should i change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're not going to have more than a 4-digit number:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR( LPAD( x, 4, '0' ), 1, 2 ) || ':' || SUBSTR( LPAD( x, 4, '0' ), 3, 2 ) AS time
FROM   test_data
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | TIME  |
> | :---- |
> | 00:07 |
> | 00:17 |
> | 03:17 |
> | 23:17 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8130b63b5ae4313e206dde1e45469e28)*

Comment: @LougEagle The db<>fiddle linked in the question is running on Oracle 11gR2 .... so, yes.

Comment: Oh you gave a link, my bad

Answer (score 1):

Use `lpad()`:

```
select lpad(floor(x / 100), 2, '0') || ':' || lpad(mod(x, 100), 2, '0')
```

Note:  This assumes that `x` is a number -- as described in the text -- rather than a string (as used in the query).

Answer (score 0):

You should pad the input with leading zeroes up to a length of 4, using LPAD.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate and then format the number:

```
to_char(n/100, 'FM00D00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=:,')
```

The optional third argument to `to_char()` replaces the usual period or comma decimal separator with a colon, making it look like a time.

```
-- CTE for sample values
with t (n) as (
  select 7 from dual
  union all
  select 17 from dual
  union all
  select 317 from dual
  union all
  select 2317 from dual
)
-- actual query
select n,
  to_char(n/100, 'FM00D00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=:,') as time
from t;

         N TIME  
---------- ------
         7 00:07 
        17 00:17 
       317 03:17 
      2317 23:17
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're dealing with here is a "mixed radix" number.

If the number is typed as a string, convert to an integer first.

You can use the remainder operator (often `MOD` or `%`, and often wrongly called the "modulus operator") to get the minute part, and integer division (often `/` or `\`) to get the hour part. In each case you'd divide by 100.

For example:

```
2317 % 100 = 17
2317 / 100 = 23

7 % 100 = 7
7 / 100 = 0
```

Apologies but I can't remember the symbol or function name for these operators in Oracle off the top of my head.

Comment: Oracle doesn't have modulus/remainder or integer division [operators](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Arithmetic-Operators.html). See Gordon's answer, which uses the `mod()` function for minutes instead, and `floor(x/100)` for the hours to get 23 instead of 23.17. Those integer parts then have to be concatenated together as strings with leading zeros, plus a colon, of course.

Comment: @AlexPoole, it must have some modulus or remainder operator if it has a MOD function! I will take the point if it has no integer division operator however - although in such cases how does it express any integer division at all without changing the return type to floating point? Does it not have a division operator for integer types, which then returns a (truncated) quotient as an integer?

Comment: `mod()` is a function, not an operator - they are different classes of things? Oracle doesn't really have an integer data type, [just `number` (and `float`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6) (with some syntactic [variants for compatibility](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-0BC16006-32F1-42B1-B45E-F27A494963FF)). Numbers can be restricted in precision/scale, but the result of 4/2 is just a plain unrestricted `number`, as is the result of 4/3.

Comment: [All of these show `Typ=2` via `dump()`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=66171c6d4462f50a626721f2a6e8a2c4), which is `NUMBER [ (p [, s]) ]` in the table linked to above. Oracle treats them all exactly the same. (`float` is a subtype, not relevant here.)

Comment: @AlexPoole, that's certainly odd, a programming language without an integer type! You've also given me a different interpretation on your original comment, which wasn't denying the existence of the MOD operation (which was how I originally took it), it was emphasising that it was a function rather than an (infix) operator. The point of my post clearly wasn't to give a code example in Oracle (which I haven't used in some time), it was to provide a name for the concept of numbers that incorporate different bases in different positions, and briefly illustrate a method to manipulate them.

Comment: @AlexPoole, I will also add I had proceeded on the assumption from the initial title that the OP wanted to manipulate the value numerically to derive the components (for further unstated use), rather than characteristically to produce a final formatted string. I had also negligently overlooked Gordon's answer for reasons I won't bore you with, so many black marks for me today!

Comment: I was trying to inform, not criticise *8-) And I can see why you might not have recognised Gordon's answer as being largely what you were describing given the operator situation. (I hadn't really thought about it before but I suppose I wouldn't really class plain SQL as a programming language. Interesting.)

Comment: @AlexPoole, yes indeed, Gordon's answer does incorporate exactly the operations to which I referred, tailored to Oracle! I have left my answer standing simply since it gives a name to the general problem of "mixed radix numbers".